# How can I find god(s)?

Tags: desktop-dungeons

I think I've played through most of the dungeons by now, and I believe I have all the Kingdom buildings.  But I still just have three gods whose altars spawn, Taurog, Tikki Tooki, and Glowing Guardian.  How do I unlock the other gods (Mystera, Dracul, Pactmaker, Earthmother)?

Comment: YAGQTOOC (Yet another good question title out of context)..

Comment: @Bora Maybe there should be a tag for that :)

Answer (score 5):

I've now located Mystera and Dracul.  I'm not sure Pactmaker and Earthmother are in the game yet, since I haven't seen them mentioned in the patch notes at all.

Each god has a subdungeon associated with them, where you must complete some requirement in order to unlock them.  We aren't entirely sure what causes the subdungeon to appear, it seems to be random at this point.  The answers currently list at least one place where the subdungeon can appear.

Mystera

> Has been found in a subdungeon of the Northern Desert.  You must find a way around the guardian of magic, using either PISORF or ENDISWAL to reach her altar.

Dracul

> Has been found in a subdungeon of the Eastern Tundra.  You must defeat "You" to reach his altar.

Taurog

> Has been found in a subdungeon of the Western Jungle. You must defeat 4 golems to reach his altar.

Glowing Guardian

> Has been found in a subdungeon of the Eastern Tundra. You must follow the path in the subdungeon and avoid any temptations as described by the signs along the way.

Tikki Tooki

> Has been found in a subdungeon of the Southern Swamp. You must defeat the imp to find his altar.

Unfortunately I can't remember where exactly I found the others, so I'm making this CW so someone else can add them.

Comment: Wasn't Taurog spawning from the very beginning?

Comment: @Dave No, jaminja's edit is correct, I remember unlocking him, I just couldn't remember which dungeon it occurred in.

Comment: so we started with 0 gods? I suppose that's possible, I just didn't pay attention to it ... if that's the case, then someone else should be able to figure out where Tikki and the Guardian were unlocked. (Or I suppose we could do it by starting another profile.)

Comment: In the beta, the Gods are introduced gradually as you play. Taurog is the only god I've unlocked so far. I've been taking my time with the beta so far. I'll update the answer if I find the others.

Comment: I have a feeling that further discussion is required regarding this answer. I have started a chat room to avoid spoilers in the comments: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1253/desktop-dungeons